# How to make a Power BI matrix to summarize multiple measures

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have data in this format, one row per person:

```
Year,Gender,Age
2020,Female,0-20
2020,Male,0-20
2021,Female,21-50
(etc)
```

I want to summarize gender and age breakdown by year in a single table, so each group of columns adds to 100%, like this:

| Year | Gender |  | Age |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **Female** | **Male** | **0-20** | **21-50** | **Over 50** |
| 2020 | 40% | 60% | 15% | 35% | 50% |
| 2021 | 45% | 55% | 12% | 39% | 49% |
| 2022 | 51% | 49% | 11% | 45% | 44% |
| 2023 | 37% | 63% | 19% | 40% | 41% |

Or like this:

| Year | Female | Male | 0-20 | 21-50 | Over 50 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 40% | 60% | 15% | 35% | 50% |
| 2021 | 45% | 55% | 12% | 39% | 49% |
| 2022 | 51% | 49% | 11% | 45% | 44% |
| 2023 | 37% | 63% | 19% | 40% | 41% |

Comment: The fastest way is to use 2 matrix visuals and hide the year column of the second matrix behind the first one. Otherwise, you may want to have a look on how to create and use so-called measures in  PowerBI. (Power BI does not work with cell references like Excel, but rather like a “database” with expanded tables) Good luck!

Comment: @Anonymous thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately I would need both matrices to scroll in sync with each other.

Comment: I see. Then you need to write a measure for each  gender and for each age bracket. Based on your data, something like this:  ```Female = COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( DataTable, ‘DataTableName’[Gender] = “Female” ) ) / COUNTROWS ( DataTable )```

Comment: Did it work out? I noticed I used ‘DataTable’ and ‘DataTableName’ but it is supposed to be the same. Also, this measure is rather simple and fully exposed to any sort of filtering that might occur from the visual used with, i.e., the wanted filtering by year. But may not work as expected, e.g., with a matrix visual, if there are further dimensions included besides the year. Those further dimensions will act as filters on this measure as well (both on the numerator and the denominator). Cheers!